# Get php date and use it in javascript with date()

Tags: javascript, php, date

I've noticed that in JavaScript, when creating a Date, months are zero based.

So I input (from a mysql php call) a value like "2019, 1, 1".
I get this value via:

```
date("Y, m, d",strtotime($mysqlcall['recorded']))
```

So input that value:

```
var foo = new Date(2019, 1, 1)
```

but it produces February 1st 2019. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Subtract 1 from the month in JavaScript.

Comment: how can I do that? And is it possible to directly change the String in php? Maybe substract -1 from "m"?

Comment: he could but thats a silly solution

Comment: `date('Y, m-1, d', strtotime($mysqlcall['recorded']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` class:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2020-01-01 00:00:00'); // Happy new year!
$month = $date->format('m') - 1;

echo $date->format('Y-' . $month . '-d H:i:s');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime

Comment: glad i could help!